# Join inside a trigger

Tags: mysql, join, triggers

I'm having problems trying to create the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER loteria_loterias AFTER UPDATE ON loteria_loterias
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE
  loteria_loterias l
  JOIN loteria_tipos t
    ON l.tipo = t.id
SET
  NEW.fecha_fin = NEW.fecha_ini + interval t.duracion hour
WHERE c.cID=NEW.cID;
END
```

I have this definitions for the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `loteria_loterias` (
 `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `tipo` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `fecha_ini` datetime NOT NULL,
 `fecha_fin` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `ganador` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `ganador` (`ganador`),
 KEY `tipo` (`tipo`),
 CONSTRAINT `loteria_loterias_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`tipo`) REFERENCES `loteria_tipos` (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `loteria_loterias_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ganador`) REFERENCES `tegm_users` (`user_login`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1



CREATE TABLE `loteria_tipos` (
 `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `nombre` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
 `coste` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `premio` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `duracion` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '(en horas)',
 `activa` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `x` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '(coordenadas del cartel)',
 `y` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '(coordenadas del cartel)',
 `z` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '(coordenadas del cartel)',
 UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
 KEY `id_2` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

According to MySQL:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `ON` keyword:

```
CREATE TRIGGER loteria_loterias AFTER UPDATE ON loteria_loterias
                                             ^^
```

Comment: Corrected. But I am still getting an error (I have updated the question) :S

Comment: @Trollkemada: In [your latest update](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17490965/2), you appear to have removed the `;` that was terminating the `UPDATE` command.

Comment: @Trollkemada: It is likely that you have not changed your client's statement delimiter, so it believes that the `CREATE TRIGGER` command terminates upon the first encountered `;`. You should change your client's statement delimiter to something else: in the MySQL command line tool, one can use the `delimiter` [command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-commands.html). Alternatively, since your trigger only contains a single command, there is no need for a `BEGIN ... END` compound statement block: removal of which will avoid the need to embed statement delimiters within the trigger's body.